# How to add custom elements to a SUMO map?

Tags: reactjs, xml, openstreetmap, sumo, overpass-api

I perform a OSM query for retrieving highways. That I later convert in SUMO with netconvert and polyconvert. This stage works fine.

Now, I have a set of Antennas I want to show on the map. I've tried to look online but I'm unable to find a solution. Each antenna has a lon and a lat and I want to show it as an element on SUMO.
I've tried adding this tag to the OSM file:

```
<node id="1" visible="true" version="3" lat="42.3422619" lon="12.4698079">
<tag k="man_made" v="antenna"/>
<tag k="tower:type" v="communication"/>
</node>
```

However, it doesn't work after the conversion. Here is the command I run:

```
netconvert --osm-files download.osm -o test.net.xml -t osmNetconvert.typ.xml --xml-validation never
polyconvert --net-file test.net.xml --osm-files download.osm --type-file typemap.xml -o map.poly.xml --xml-validation never
```

Here is my osmNetconvert.typ.xml:

```
<types xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://sumo.dlr.de/xsd/types_file.xsd">
    <type id="highway.motorway"       numLanes="2" speed="39.44" priority="14" oneway="true"  disallow="rail rail_urban rail_electric rail_fast tram ship pedestrian bicycle moped"/>
    <type id="highway.trunk"          numLanes="2" speed="27.78" priority="13" oneway="false" disallow="rail rail_urban rail_electric rail_fast tram ship pedestrian bicycle"/>
    <type id="highway.primary"        numLanes="2" speed="27.78" priority="12" oneway="false" disallow="rail rail_urban rail_electric rail_fast tram ship"/>
    <type id="highway.secondary"      numLanes="1" speed="27.78" priority="11" oneway="false" disallow="rail rail_urban rail_electric rail_fast tram ship"/>
    <type id="highway.tertiary"       numLanes="1" speed="22.22" priority="10" oneway="false" disallow="rail rail_urban rail_electric rail_fast tram ship"/>
    <type id="highway.motorway_link"  numLanes="1" speed="22.22" priority="9"  oneway="true"  disallow="rail rail_urban rail_electric rail_fast tram ship pedestrian bicycle moped"/>
    <type id="highway.trunk_link"     numLanes="1" speed="22.22" priority="8"  oneway="false" disallow="rail rail_urban rail_electric rail_fast tram ship pedestrian bicycle"/>
    <type id="highway.primary_link"   numLanes="1" speed="22.22" priority="7"  oneway="false" disallow="rail rail_urban rail_electric rail_fast tram ship"/>
    <type id="highway.secondary_link" numLanes="1" speed="22.22" priority="6"  oneway="false" disallow="rail rail_urban rail_electric rail_fast tram ship"/>
    <type id="highway.tertiary_link"  numLanes="1" speed="22.22" priority="5"  oneway="false" disallow="rail rail_urban rail_electric rail_fast tram ship"/>
    <type id="highway.unclassified"   numLanes="1" speed="13.89" priority="4"  oneway="false" disallow="rail rail_urban rail_electric rail_fast tram ship"/>
    <type id="highway.residential"    numLanes="1" speed="13.89" priority="3"  oneway="false" disallow="rail rail_urban rail_electric rail_fast tram ship"/>
    <type id="highway.living_street"  numLanes="1" speed="2.78"  priority="2"  oneway="false" disallow="rail rail_urban rail_electric rail_fast tram ship"/>
    <type id="highway.unsurfaced"     numLanes="1" speed="8.33"  priority="1"  oneway="false" disallow="rail rail_urban rail_electric rail_fast tram ship"/>
    <type id="highway.service"        numLanes="1" speed="5.56"  priority="1"  oneway="false" allow="delivery pedestrian bicycle"/>

    <!-- everything which serves mainly pedestrians is oneway because all current pedestrian models do not care about direction -->
    <type id="highway.track"          numLanes="1" speed="5.56"  priority="1"  oneway="false"           allow="motorcycle moped pedestrian bicycle"/>
    <type id="highway.footway"        numLanes="1" speed="2.78"  priority="1"  oneway="true"  width="2" allow="pedestrian"/>
    <type id="highway.pedestrian"     numLanes="1" speed="2.78"  priority="1"  oneway="true"  width="2" allow="pedestrian"/>
    <type id="highway.path"           numLanes="1" speed="5.56"  priority="1"  oneway="false" width="2" allow="pedestrian bicycle"/>
    <type id="highway.bridleway"      numLanes="1" speed="2.78"  priority="1"  oneway="true"  width="2" allow="pedestrian"/>
    <type id="highway.cycleway"       numLanes="1" speed="5.56"  priority="1"  oneway="false" width="1" allow="bicycle"/>
    <type id="highway.step"           numLanes="1" speed="1.39"  priority="1"  oneway="true"  width="2" allow="pedestrian"/>
    <type id="highway.steps"          numLanes="1" speed="1.39"  priority="1"  oneway="true"  width="2" allow="pedestrian"/>
    <type id="highway.stairs"         numLanes="1" speed="1.39"  priority="1"  oneway="true"  width="2" allow="pedestrian"/>

    <type id="highway.bus_guideway"   numLanes="1" speed="27.78" priority="1"  oneway="true"  allow="bus"/>
    <type id="highway.raceway"        numLanes="2" speed="83.33" priority="15" oneway="false" allow="vip"/>
    <type id="highway.ford"           numLanes="1" speed="2.78"  priority="1"  oneway="false" allow="army"/>

    <type id="railway.preserved"      numLanes="1" speed="27.78" priority="16" oneway="true"  allow="rail"/>
    <type id="railway.tram"           numLanes="1" speed="13.89" priority="17" oneway="true"  allow="tram"/>
    <type id="railway.subway"         numLanes="1" speed="27.78" priority="18" oneway="true"  allow="rail_urban"/>
    <type id="railway.light_rail"     numLanes="1" speed="27.78" priority="19" oneway="true"  allow="rail_urban"/>
    <type id="railway.rail"           numLanes="1" speed="44.44" priority="20" oneway="true"  allow="rail"/>
    <type id="railway.highspeed"      numLanes="1" speed="69.44" priority="21" oneway="true"  allow="rail_fast"/>

    <!--
    <type id="highway.construction"   numLanes="1" speed="13.89" priority="4"  oneway="false" disallow="rail rail_urban rail_electric rail_fast tram ship" discard="true"/>
    -->
</types>
```

What am I doing wrong? How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

You can place arbitrary POIs using SUMO's netedit, see https://sumo.dlr.de/docs/Netedit/elementsShape.html. This is also possible with an XML file:

```
<additional>
    <poi id="antenna1" lat="10" lon="20"/>
</additional>
```

which can then be loaded in sumo-gui using the `-a` option